# create stack using 2 queues

Tags: python, stack, queue

Hey guys I am having trouble with my first assignment in my data structures class, and was hopping someone could provide some insight on what I am doing wrong.

I must create a stack that utilizes 2 queues for data storage.

```
import Queue_PlistLR as queueList

import Queue_PlistLR as queueList

class Stack_2Queues():

        def __init__(self, name, salary):
                self.items = []
                self.name = name
                self.salary = salary

        def isEmpty(self):
                return len(self.items) == 0        

        def push(self, e):
                self._data.append(e)

        def pop(self):
                if self.is_empty:
                        raiseEmpty("Stack is empty")
                return self._data.pop()
        def size(self):
                return len(self.items) 

        def to_String(self):
                str_i = ""
                for e in self.items:
                        str_i+=str(e)+" "
                return str_i.strip() 

        def length(self):

                return len()

        def enqueue(self, item):
                self.items.append(item)

        def dequeue(self):
                if self.isEmpty():
                        raise Empty('Queue is empty')
                return self.items.pop(0)        

        def employeeName(self):
                print("The employee is: ", self.name)

        def employeeSalary(self):

                print("Employees salary is", self.salary)        

s1 = Stack_2Queues = [["Ash", "Jen", "Mike", "Zach"], [45000, 32000, 74000, 960000]]

s1.employeeName()
s1.employeeSalary()
```

***I know this is wrong, for the most part. but my question is this. For the stack I want to create 2 queues, one for employeeName and the other for employeeSalary, using 1 stack.

Also when I try printing the name and salary from the stack (to see if it works) and I get "list has no attribute" error.***

So, here are my questions:

1) Excuse my illiteracy as this may sound stupid, but is my s1 variable the form of a stack?

2) Why am I getting the list has no attribute since I defined all methods, and called them?

Comment: Please format your code: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 2):

The `AttributeError` is caused by this line:

```
s1 = Stack_2Queues = [["Ash", "Jen", "Mike", "Zach"], [45000, 32000, 74000, 960000]]
```

This is not how you initialize `Stack_2Queues`. What's actually going here is that you're assigning the list which contains two other lists to the variables `s1` and `Stack_2Queues`(thus changing the reference which points to the class definition to the list)

```
In [1]: s1 = Stack_2Queues = [["Ash", "Jen", "Mike", "Zach"], [45000, 32000, 74000, 960000]]

In [2]: print(s1)
[['Ash', 'Jen', 'Mike', 'Zach'], [45000, 32000, 74000, 960000]]

In [3]: print(Stack_2Queues)
[['Ash', 'Jen', 'Mike', 'Zach'], [45000, 32000, 74000, 960000]]
```

Simple example to understand this:

```
In [4]: a = 5

In [5]: b = 5
```

This is equivalent to:

```
In [6]: a = b = 5
```

Change the line to this:

```
s1 = Stack_2Queues(["Ash", "Jen", "Mike", "Zach"], [45000, 32000, 74000, 960000])
```

It works for me after that:

```
('The employee is: ', ['Ash', 'Jen', 'Mike', 'Zach'])
('Employees salary is', [45000, 32000, 74000, 960000])
```

Also you imported the same module twice right at the top of the script which you haven't used.

If you try to call either `push` or `pop` on an instance of `Stack_2Queues` python will throw another `AttributeError` because `Stack_2Queues` does not have any `_data` attribute.

```
def push(self, e):
    self._data.append(e)

def pop(self):
    if self.is_empty:
        raiseEmpty("Stack is empty")
    return self._data.pop()
```

You should maybe change this part of the code or add `self._data` in the `__init__` method.

This will also not work:

```
def length(self):
    return len()
```

Calling the built-in `len` function without any argument will throw an error. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#len
It's probably redundant since you defined a `size` method and probably does the same thing.